# What's this winged toy figure in Ant-Man?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, props, ant-man

I don't recognize it, but it shows up in two very different places in the movie.

It appears in Hank's junk drawer at 00:24:35

[image: Hank's junk drawer]

And earlier in the Baskin-Robbin's manager's office at 00:05:28

[image: Baskin-Robbin's manager's office]

Comment: I suspect it's actually an *angel* but I can't find anything on it. This is really unimportant *trivia* though.

Comment: That's a funny-looking "eagle"! Looks more like an angel or Cupid figure to me - a baby human with white feathered wings

Comment: @BrettFromLA It has a beak! :D

Comment: @DarthLocke Guess I'm looking at it differently than you because I don't see a beak. In the first pic, it's a kid with his arms open, a giant mouth (??), and no legs. In the second pic, it's a kid with his arms together (praying?), with a thing stickup up off his head. Both of them have wings.

Comment: @thirdender this may be stetech, but if it is a bird, I wonder if it foreshadows the next film, as Kurt compares Ghost to the Russian Folklore witch Baba Yaga? She is often presented with "bird-like" features including claws and a long nose.

Comment: This kind of question isn't normally what is discussed here, because as Paulie_D points out, it's *trivia*. You might get a better response at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ where superhero movies are on-topic.